# How to get Class object from parametrized List for input to new object declaration?

Tags: java, generics, reflection

I rewrited this line of code:

```
JsonResponse<LoginResult> response = new JsonResponse<>(LoginResult.class);
```

to this:

```
JsonResponse<LoginResult[]> response = new JsonResponse<>(LoginResult[].class);
```

Because I wanted to pass the array of LoginResults.

But now I would like to rewrite it using ArrayList and of course I stuck in this:

```
JsonResponse<List<LoginResult>> response = new JsonResponse<List<LoginResult>>(List<LoginResult>.class);
```

I understand that I cannot get Class object from parametrized type. I read a lot of topics how to do that but I am not sure how to rewrite code in my situation, because I need the Class object as the input for JSonResponse constructor?

```
public class JsonResponse<T> extends JsonRequest {

    private Type type;

    public JsonResponse(Class<T> type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public Type getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(Type type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public T getResult() {
        return (T) getAttribute(RESULT);
    }
}
```

Can you help me or give me some clue how solve this problem? Thank you!

Comment: What are you using `type` for in your `JsonResponse` class? Right now, you're not using `type` so you can just remove it and your problem is gone. And how to resolve your problem depends on what you do with `type`.

Answer (score 3):

You can create a wrapper class for this list, something like:

```
public class LoginResultList {

    private List<LoginResult> loginResultList;

    // getters, setters etc...

}
```

Or you could inherit this container class from the `ArrayList` itself:

```
public class LoginResultList extends ArrayList<LoginResult> {}
```

Comment: Thanks for help! It works but now I would like to know why Java is not able to recognize or return me the type of parametrized List? It is obvious that the type stored in the List is (will be) in my case LoginResult, isn't it?

Comment: At runtime, this list can contain anything, because there is no information about parameterized types at runtime due to type erasure. So you can't reference a type "List parameterized with LoginResult", because at runtime there is no such type (unless you explicitly create it, like in my example). You can read more about type erasure here, for example http://www.baeldung.com/java-type-erasure

Answer (score 1):

You can find the `JsonResponse`'s generic type parameter from any subclass, including an anonymous one.

```
public class JsonResponse<T> {

  private Type type;

  public JsonResponse() {
    Class<?> curClass = this.getClass();
    if (curClass == JsonResponse.class) {
      // not a subclass with a type parameter, so assume the response
      // is just an Object.
      type = Object.class;
    }
    else {
      // in case it's not a direct subclass, search upward for JsonResponse
      while (curClass.getSuperclass() != JsonResponse.class) {
        curClass = curClass.getSuperclass();
      }

      // get the generic type information for JsonResponse
      Type responseType = curClass.getGenericSuperclass();
      if (!(responseType instanceof ParameterizedType)) {
        throw new IllegalStateException(
          "JsonResponse type definition should have been parameterized.");
      }
      Type[] responseTypeParams =
          ((ParameterizedType) responseType).getActualTypeArguments();

      // get the only type parameter, <T>
      type = responseTypeParams[0];
    }
  }

  public Type getType() {
    return type;
  }
}
```

Now you can get the generic type information, as long as you actually instantiate it as an anonymous type:

```java
// instantiate as an anonymous subclass (the "{}")
JsonResponse<?> response = new JsonResponse<List<String>>() {};
System.out.println(response.getType());
// outputs "java.util.List<java.lang.String>"
```

Comment: Thanks for your advice as well! It is interesting approach.